# How to use square brackets in a WYSIWYG editor to post-process text?

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I need to obfuscate email addresses before they are published on my users' sites, to prevent spambots from scraping them. However, some users like to use mailto links (against my advice, but they do what they will), and my obfuscation function breaks the mailtos. So I'd like to make it easy for site admins to slap obfuscation around some email addresses but not others.

I want to use syntax like this:

```
"Some text, some more text, an [emailaddress@example.com], and more text."
```

Which will output

```
"Some text, some more text, an emailaddress<span class='obfuscate' style='display:none;'>@</span>example.com, and more text."
```

Is there a standard way to get PHP to evaluate and process only the text in the square brackets? I've seen similar notation in Wordpress code, for example,

```
[contact-form-7]
```

is typed in the WYSIWYG editor, and will be rendered as a fully formed contact form to the public. So how can I do that?

Comment: You can probably do a `preg_match()` expression and then act upon the proper returned array value (i.e. create function to format it the way you want). If you create a function to process the returned value, you can add more commands in the future not just `[email@address.com]`.

Comment: You can also do a `preg_replace()` expression if email is all you need...

Comment: It is called BBCode, and there are tons of scripts out there where you can hook in your own custom "rules", as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this regular expression: [[\w.]+@[\w]+.[\w]+] to find email addresses enclosed in square brackets, and replaced them with the obfuscated string.